# I need to remove an entire json blob/object if it contains the file name/path from and external file with contains known duplicates

Tags: python, json, pandas

How would I strip out strings that start with: {"filename": "\\network\test\etc\file0001.tif and end with }]}]}

The length of the objects differ depending on size, content of the files.

I'm starting to figure out dataframes/pandas in python and I don't understand general json structure yet.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('Filelist.json')
--ColA in the index = "filename" (Need help here)--
dups = pd.read_csv('Deleted_Duplicates.csv')

df_final = df.loc[~df.ColA.isin(dups.Duplicates),:]

df_final.to_json('Filelist_NoDupes.csv',index=False)
```

I would expect I could ignore which column the filename is in, using the external list to strip out entire rows/objects and output the new file.

Comment: sounds like a classic regex problem. You can find a lot of ideas here: https://regexr.com/. Also, it would be helpful to have a sample json file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure out the proper escaping because you don't have a working example to test, but it will be something like this:

```
df_final = df.loc[~df.ColA.str.match(pat = '\{"filename"\: "\\\\network\\test\\etc\\file0001.tif.*\}\]\}\]\}') ,:]
```